# Firestore Geopoint in an Arrays

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am working with an interesting scenario that I am not sure can work, or will work well. With my current project I am trying to find an efficient way of working with geopoints in firestore. The straight forward approach where a document can contain a *geopoints* field is pretty self explanatory and easy to query. However, I am having to work with a varying amount of *geopoints* for a single document (Article). The reason for this is because a specific piece of content may need to be available in more than one geographic area.

For example, An article may need to be available only in NYC, Denver and Seattle. Using a geopoint for each location and searching by radius, in general, is a pretty standard task if I only wanted the article to be available in Seattle, but now it needs to be available in two more places.

The solution as I see it currently is to use an array and fill it with geopoints.  The structure would look something like this:

```
articleText (String),
sortTime (Timestamp),
tags (Array)
 - ['tagA','tagB','tagC','tagD'],
availableLocations (Array)
 - [(Geopoint), (Geopoint), (Geopoint), (Geopoint)]
```

Then performing a query to get all content within 10 miles of a specific Geopoint starting at a specific postTime.

What I don't know is if putting the geopoints in an array works well or should be avoided in favor or another data structure.

I have considered replicating an article document for each geopoint, but that does not scale very well if more than a handful of locations needs defining. I've also considered creating a "reference" collection where each point is a document that contains the documentID of an article, but this leads to reading each reference document then reading the actual document. Essentially two document reads for 1 piece of content, which can get expensive based on the Firestore pricing model, and may slow things down unnecessarily.

Am I approaching this in an acceptable way? And are there other methods that can work more efficiently?